# Creating custom RichTextBox control

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, controls, richtextbox

I believe am in need of creating custom `RichTextBox` in C#. One kind of like that:

[image: Custom C# RichTextBox]

I admit it might not even have to be `RichTextBox`, but after some research I decided it's gonna be the easiest way. Functionality I need are icons at each row, checkboxes and text formatting. My program will process each line of the text and mark lines that are correct, incorrect, and strike out lines not necessary in further work, while showing line that's currently processed and allowing user to edit some lines freely (here: lines before *Around 3 000* won't be editable, but those under the line will).

What's the problem then? I have no idea how to get it done. I've seen tutorial on [how to make single-line `textBox` with icon or checkbox nearby](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Controls/ListBox_and_ComboBox/TextBox_Icon/article.asp), but I have no idea how to make both, and for multiline textBox (so I could freely scroll and everything would work fluently). I've read some questions on SO as well, but neither helped me.

I just don't know how to get started, I realize it won't be 5 min work, but I'm willing to do it. Until now I've been only able to create custom control deriving from `RichTextBox`, but I have no idea which methods and how to override. Any help appreciated.

Comment: as suggestion (not answer) use ListBox "Owner Drawn" and the textBox you mentioned (when editing use the textBox otherwise use the listBox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser) control instead [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox).

You can add `CheckBoxes` and editable content by setting a correct `HTML` code to it.

Set each `TextBox` or `CheckBoxe`s ids and use [`GetElementsByTagName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname) or [`GetElementById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid) to access inner elements to get or set its attributes or values.

Comment: Now that's very interesting idea... Have you got any idea what would be performance of such solution? I will need to access every line quite frequently, how can I access editBoxes inside WebBrowser freely?

Comment: use [HtlmElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementcollection)